# Do I download the Firestore Bundle Builder Admin Dashboard into the local project directory or a separate directory?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-extensions

I am learning React Native and Firestore as I go building a project. I am trying to bundle some data and I would like to use the bundle builder extenstion for my project. I am following the documentation for this extension but one piece of the instructions is unclear to me. I am supposed to clone the bundle builder from github as the first step but I do not know where I am supposed to clone this. I am using Expo to create my project and I am wondering if I need to clone this into the directory of my expo project or does this need to go into it's own directory?

I have tried downloading into it's own directory and I have not been able to get it to work. I wanted to double check before I download it into my Expo project directory and accidently mess something up.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the documentation on [Using the Firestore Bundle Builder Extension](https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions/official/firestore-bundle-builder) that you seem to be following, it seems that [building and serving the bundle](https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions/official/firestore-bundle-builder#building_and_serving_the_bundle) actually accesses your Firestore instance - so that needs to run in the same Firebase project as where your data resides.

It does **not** become part of your Expo app though. Instead it becomes a separate web site on Firebase Hosting and Cloud Functions when you [deploy the site](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/test-preview-deploy#deploy-project-directory-to-live) (that's the same link as included in the docs).